# Unable to build project with CoreData classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to migrate my sandpit code into my main project but for some reason I am getting the following strange error when trying to compile

> syntax error before 'NSManagedObjectModel'

At first I thought this was because coredata wasnt in the prefix.pch file but I have added it in there too.

This is the top of AppDelegate where the code is being used (straight out of an Apple example)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppSettings.h"
#import "Skin.h"

@interface JeanieAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` and don't forget to link it in.

Comment: thanks coding at 2.30am has its downsides! Especially when the wireless keyboard AND mouse batteries die!

Answer (score 0):

Also, beware adding just anything to your .pch file.  When you do so, those header files will be included all throughout your projectYou should only really put things there that are truly going to be universally required all through your project.